# How to install Freetube in Ubuntu 22.04 armhf?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, youtube, arm

I am trying to install Freetube in Ubuntu 22.04 armhf (Raspberry Pi image) running in a Surface RT.

[Freetube](https://freetubeapp.io/#download) only provides .deb files for amd64 and arm64 architectures.
Flatpak stopped supporting armhf, and the armhf version of Freetube available on Flatpak is outdated (it does not load Youtube videos anymore, probably due to change of API).

Is there any way to install Freetube on armhf Ubuntu? How can I compile (or preferably cross-compile) Freetube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently there was a [pull request](https://github.com/FreeTubeApp/FreeTube/pull/2113) in GitHub to generate the armhf build with GitHub actions. It will be available in the release page from the next version.

---

While there has been no release since the pull request has been accepted, GitHub generates new [binaries](https://github.com/FreeTubeApp/FreeTube/actions/runs/3074318250) from each commit, and the armhf version from the latest commit can be downloaded.

Here is the download link for the .deb file generated from the commit on 17th September 2022: https://github.com/FreeTubeApp/FreeTube/suites/8340728925/artifacts/367007755

---

FreeTube works on my Surface RT tablet. While it is a bit choppy on 720p (the NVidia graphics of this tablet does not work in GNU/Linux), videos work very well in 360p (and in 480p, to some extend).

[image]